# FullScreen Browser on page load in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, browser

I googled this but didn't find working solution of the problem. After logging in I've to open page in FullScreen mode as in F11 mode in mozilla and chrome.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use javascript to accomplish this try adding this code after a user is logged in:

```
string script = "<script language=’JavaScript’> window.name = ‘windowname’;open(”, ‘windowname’); window.close();window.open(‘home.aspx’, ”, ‘fullscreen=yes,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,titlebar=no,addressbar=no’);</script>";

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), “PopupScript”, script, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

if i am not wrong, you cant make fullscreen browser in asp.net, you can do like this alternativiley

```
<asp:Button id="btnClick" runat="server" OnClientClick="window.open('yourUrl','', 'fullscreen=yes, scrollbars=auto');"/>
```